# how to split xml and non xml content from variable to new variable in php

Tags: php, xml

sample contents present in my variable are

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 07:07:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 280
Content-Type: text/html

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<serviceResponse>                 
 <status>Success</status>
 <error/> 
 <pool_balance>100.00</pool_balance> 
 <kcm_wallet_balance>51.01</kcm_wallet_balance>                 
 <glo_wallet_balance>0.00</glo_wallet_balance>                 
</serviceResponse>
```

**I want only this part**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <serviceResponse>                 
     <status>Success</status>
     <error/> 
     <pool_balance>100.00</pool_balance> 
     <kcm_wallet_balance>51.01</kcm_wallet_balance>                 
     <glo_wallet_balance>0.00</glo_wallet_balance>                 
    </serviceResponse>
```

no idea how to fetch those contents in seperate varaible

Comment: Are you reading a xml file or a text file with xml content

Comment: no i am getting this output from curl in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false` to remove this from response

try to set `CURLOPT_HEADER` to `false`.